# Angular CLI(v.1.0.1) doesn't allow subdomain for Developement Purspose : Invalid Host Headers

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

I am developing a multitenant system I was using Angular CLI 1.0.0 So when I go to localhost or asd.localhost(*.localhost) regex .It serves the application normally. Last I upgraded to 1.0.1. When I go to asd.localhost It says **Invalid Host Headers** .They say webpack has put some security patch. How can I allow subdomain to angular application for development purspose.

Comment: I too have same problem. Have you found any solutions yet ? If yes then please post it on SO, if not then what is your quick temporary solution, if any ?

Comment: The issue is resolved.Check it out. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6070

Answer (score 5):

> Just use "--disable-host-check" parameter

```
ng serve --disable-host-check
```

> Enjoy!